# Automation issue with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation

This is a basic script to test some automation features in powershell and it is suppose to check for a font window, and then fill out the fields.

```
read-host "Press ENTER to continue..."
$wshell.AppActivate("font") 
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys("$style{TAB}$texture{TAB}$size{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")
```

This works the way expect, but when put into a function, the output changes. For some reason the output is put all into the first field and seems like it is never tabbed. The enter is executed but for whatever reason, the tabs are not being used.

```
function font($style,$texture,$size){
    read-host "Press ENTER to continue..."
    $wshell.AppActivate("font") 
    Sleep 1
    $wshell.SendKeys("$style{TAB}$texture{TAB}$size{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")
}
font("Arial", "Bold", 12)
```

Overall the question is why will the script not tab when ran as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling functions in powershell, you don't surround the parameters in parentheses.

So instead of

```
font("Arial", "Bold", 12)
```

Try

```
font "Arial" "Bold" 12
```